# Can we have a consecutive days counter on our profile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile)

I'm a freaking addict. I swear I've been on SO every day since... a long time ago!

Maybe we can have a consecutive days counter on our profile?

Answer (score 2):

If you really care about the badge that much, you can use the wall behind you to record your visits :)

(Not really; if you were a real addict, you should have earned Fanatic by now.)