# Counter for Fanatic and woot! Badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, activity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile)

Would a counter of how many days we've been on Stack Overflow in a row be a good idea? As I envision it, if we were to have a counter on our profile pages that probably only we can see, it would be somewhat helpful.

What do you think?

Comment: and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20968/can-we-have-a-consecutive-days-counter-on-our-profile

Comment: @warren no, that's a related one, because here I'm asking if we can have a counter of how many days in a row we've visited, not just for the badge.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile

Comment: ok, the second one is a dupe. You're right. However, I'm following that one's dupe links, too, and no answer was reached whether or not this could be attained (such a feature, I mean). What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though this is a dupe...

I don't see what value this would have. Statistics that are visible to the user should have some sort of value beyond the badge that they count towards, and daily visits simply doesn't. No one else is going to care that I've visited the site 80 days in a row. Once I've earned the badges they can bask in my glory, but until then, what's the point? :)

Even if the counter is only visible to me, it seems like extra fluff that doesn't really help me contribute to the site in any way (unlike encouraging me to vote, edit posts, and answer questions).