# What are the exact requirements for the woot/enthusiast badge?

Tags: support, status-completed, activity-badges

I've visited the site (SO, MSO and SU) at least 30 days in a row. I'm not entirely sure, but I may even have done 100 days in a row. However, I have not gotten the enthusiast/woot badge. My timezone is GMT.

Are there any other requirements?

I'm guessing at a few possible causes:

1. My "day" is not equal to a SO "day" (timezones maybe, I'm in GMT).
2. There is a minimum activity requirement (some days I just read a few questions).
3. The badge is awarded when you stop visiting.
4. It requires an actual login. I stay logged in at times.

Are any of these correct, or if not, what is the actual cause?

Comment: Are you sure it's not that you actually have a life?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are GMT you are on server-time, so your days match.

Looking at the SO log; I see gaps (not all missing days shown):

- 5th Oct
- etc
- 8th Sep
- etc
- 15th Aug
- etc
- 24th Jul
- etc

So I don't know what the minumum activity is, but *whatever* it is, there are gaps. Is it possible that you weren't logged in on those days? Did you clean down your cookies perhaps, and not notice the big yellow bar at the top?

To get the badge you must visit *every* day in a contiguous block.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that I missed days. "Did you clean down your cookies perhaps, and not notice the big yellow bar at the top?" This must be what happened.

Comment: Is there a way for us to track our own logins?

Comment: Not as far as I know, no.

Comment: Marc's comment immediately above this one is now wrong. The user profile shows users their own "consecutive visit counts" as of mid-2010.

Comment: I visit StackOverflow every weekday and often on the weekends. Was going to try for the fanatic badge but I don't seen to get credit for my daily logins.

Comment: @Todd just going to the home page isn't enough. Have you been doing anything in particular on the site?

Comment: @Gravell. Thanks, I see the folly of my ways now.

Answer (score 9):

1. GMT is the timezone SO "days" are based on.
2. The only minimum activity required is being logged in and coming to the site
3. The badge is award on day 30 (for `enthusiast`, 100 for `fanatic`)
4. If you're logged in, you're logged in, you do not need to log out and log back in each day

So no, it shouldn't be any of those. I would guess you actually missed a day in there at some point, but only a <del>SO team member</del> moderator can check the actual logs of your activity in the DB.

Comment: Stupid question, but is there no way for us to check our own activity?

Comment: No, but I have proposed a feature that would show you the number of consecutive days you've visited the site. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865