# Consecutive Day Reset

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I'm not sure this is the same problem as the [Inconsistent consecutive days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days) bug that is reported, but maybe more like the [problem this user had](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55394/why-did-my-consecutive-days-disappear). I'd post under that topic, but it appears to have been resolved as "By Design".

I've been monitoring my consecutive days recently and yesterday had a total of 12 consecutive days, yet today when I first look I had one, but now I have two consecutive days. Am I missing something? I work in GMT, so there is little chance of "missing the Stack Overflow day". I don't necessarily answer a lot of questions, but I have recently been visiting my profile page to check badges / rep / consecutive days, and the homepage (and unanswered questions) for questions I can answer.

My guess is that it thinks that I missed Sunday (as that was the day 2 days ago ;) ). I'm pretty sure I at least visited the SO homepage in that time and maybe additional pages (though, that I can't be sure of).

Is there something more than just visiting stack overflow that you need to do to acquire a visit? View two pages / the homepage is excluded?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29303/enthusiast-fanatic-badge-do-we-need-to-just-visit-or-participate and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/me-want-to-badge-up-how-can-what-do and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24884/what-are-the-exact-requirements-for-the-woot-enthusiast-badge all cover the requirements - you really need nothing more than a page visit. Always check your user profile to see your last activity or seen field, to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your consecutive days by clicking the date on your user page. See here:

[Implementation date for the consecutive days calendar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/implementation-date-for-the-consecutive-days-calendar)