# Etiquette Question: Is There A Way to Contact Moderators for Specific Reputation/Badge Questions?

Tags: support, etiquette, activity-badges, consecutive-days

Sometimes I wonder if if the badge system is working properly.  But also I could just be confused and it could very well be me not remembering what I did, i.e., how many consecutive days visiting Superuser...  Or thinking I voted for questions when I voted for answers.  Would it be inline with this board's policy to ask a specif-user question like, "how many consecutive days have I visited Superuser?"  Or is this a no-no?  I know the moderators are busy with other issues (so I wouldn't necessarily want to contact them directly).  But I think enough users would like some stats on consecutive days visited and ratios of votes (questions/answers, for example) so it seems valid to ask such questions.  Plus, I really like participating on Superuser and visiting a site for 100 days in a row seems like a good goal to have.

Comment: In addition to the answers you've already received below, also consider Jeff's reasoning [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too/34440#34440).

Comment: Yes, I read that a few days ago...  And that is mostly how I view things.  But a couple badges have caught my attention, and now I want them (can you blame me?  The Stack Exchange sites are quite fun, if you ask me), so I am somewhat obsessed...

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't ask that on the site itself, and you might ask it here, but generally it's best to flag for mod attention one of your post with the inquiry. If it requires an answer, he can send you an e-mail.

If you do come here, you'll likely get the answer on the spot, and may be even a short explanation on how to do it yourself.

Comment: An explanation on how to do it myself...  That would be cool.

Answer (score 3):

Meta is the place to find answers to those *types* of questions. That being said, for common questions such as what you're asking now, there are already good answers given here, so we kindly ask you to search Meta before asking (same goes for SO proper).

In general, I would not use the flagging system to ask questions like this. The flagging system should be used for important matters -- you can only flag a post once!

Regarding the number of consecutive days visiting the site, please [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile).

Comment: It appears that everyone likes the idea...  Someone (lions_leash) asked whether development was underway for this profile enhancement but no comment was provided.  The accepted answer for the post you mentioned above wasn't really an answer.  It seems the code provide by Rob might be taken into consideration...  Anyway, it seems enough people like this idea so I'm sure it will happen with time.  Thanks!

Comment: @nicorellius: Around here, bigtime support doesn't *always* translate into an implementation in the end, but it definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

A question like *"how many consecutive days have I missed"* can, at present, only be answered by the dev team and diamond moderators.

The best way to get that question answered would be to flag one of your posts for moderator attention and request it.  The moderator who responds can drop the answer into the email you've included in your profile, or can comment on one of your posts.  Personally, I'd send it to the user's email if they've provided one.

I think most moderators provide contact emails in their profiles; it would not be unreasonable to email this request directly to a moderator.  Flagging a post is probably better, since any moderator on a site can see and answer it.

The diamond moderators are here to help, but understand that this kind of request is **very low priority**.  So ask nicely, ask once, and patiently await a reply.  Don't be surprised if it takes a day or two.

Comment: A question like *"what's my current question/answer voting ratio"* can only be answered by the dev team.  Moderator flags requesting this will probably go unanswered.

Comment: Thanks quack quixote for your help...