# Viewing another user's consecutive days calendar is broken for mods

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, consecutive-days, profile-page

Moderators can see the consecutive days visited in a user's profile, and it's [clickable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile) to show the calendar, but the request fails with:

> An error occurred when loading days visited history.

The site does a request for `/users/daily-site-access/USER_ID`, which returns a 404 if `USER_ID` isn't the requesting user's. It should probably return results for any `USER_ID` if the requesting user is a mod, or the link shouldn't be clickable from the profile (the first seems logical, since mods can see user history anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported internally and will be fixed on the next deployment.