# Consecutive days information on new profile page

Tags: support, consecutive-days

I am trying to get the following participation badges

- Enthusiast - Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)
- Fanatic - Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)

On the old profile page [image needed :D] we used to have a counter for `days I visited the site` and `consecutive days`. Is that information still available somewhere else?

I tried choosing `Fanatic` as my next badge. It shows me a bar with the counter of days in a row that I have logged in, but no calendar or anything.

[image]

Here is a [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile) to the discussion when the counter was created in 2009.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's there, under the "Profile" tab:

[image]

Click on the stat to view more.

Comment: I see now, I was on activity page... Cool, thanks :D